# Traduction de « reviewer of a journal »

Tags: traduction, science

Quelle est la traduction correcte en français du substantif *reviewer* dans la phrase ci-après :

> He is a reviewer for the Journal of Mechanics.

J'ai vu plusieurs mots tels que *relecteur*, *critique*, *réviseur*, *évaluateur*.

Peut-on utiliser le mot même *reviewer* en français ?

Comment: Comme souvent, une explication sur le sens attendu du mot serait bienvenue. Un critique et un relecteur ne font pas le même métier.

Comment: Vous avez raison. Cette personne évalue un article soumis dans une revue scientifique et peut proposer à l'éditeur de la revue soit la publication sans modifications, soit la publication après que l'auteur effectue des modifications/corrigés/améliorations etc ou même rejeter l'article si l'article, d'après lui, n'est pas bon pour être publié.

Comment: En consultant les exemples donnés ici, https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/reviewer+for+a+journal.html, on ne peut pas voir une interprétation unanime. Mes collègues francophones me suggèrent que j'emploie le mot même reviewer en français, mais il me paraît que cela est un anglicisme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Relecteur*/*relectrice* semble être le plus utilisé, ou en version longue *membre du comité de (re)lecture*, puisqu'on parle de « conférence avec comité de lecture » .

Voir par exemple

- [Conférence TALN 2017](http://taln2017.cnrs.fr/comites/) « comité de lecture »
- [Conférence IHM 2015](http://ihm2015.afihm.org/auteurs.html) « relecteurs »
- [Conférence PPSN VI](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00072445/document) « relecteurs »
- [Revue SPIRALE](https://spirale-edu-revue.fr/spip.php?article29) « comité de lecture »
- [Revue Parlement(s)](http://www.parlements.org/parlements/comite_de_redaction_comite_de_lecture.html) « comité de lecture »
- [Revue anthropologie et santé](http://journals.openedition.org/anthropologiesante/717#tocto1n5) « comité de lecture »
- [*Innovation et revue scientifique* (Vidal, 2006)](https://www.cairn.info/revue-distances-et-savoirs-2006-4-page-565.htm) parle de « comité de lecture » et de « relecture par les pairs ».

En pratique j'entends assez souvent *reviewer* en anglais dans le discours, mais je ne sais pas dans quelle mesure ça se généralise à d'autres domaines que le mien.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse exhaustive ! Bizarrement, le mot relecteur n'apparaît pas dans les traductions disponibles ici https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/reviewer+for+a+journal.html  Par contre, le mot relectrice est donné dans les exemples.

Comment: À part la première phrase, le reste est spécifique aux *conférences*. Dans certains domaines ça n'existe pas les relecteurs pour les conférences (p.ex. les maths), seulement pour les journaux (et j'ai rarement entendu parler du "comité de relecture" pour un journal).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Après recherche en dehors de mon domaine, je ne suis pas fou : on trouve bien « revue à comité de lecture ». Même pour celles qui n'ont pas de comité de lecture permanent (et distinct du comité de rédaction) ce n'est donc pas insensé de parler de *relecteur/relectrice*.

Comment: Bon alors c'est peut-être mon expérience en maths qui me biaise...

Answer (score 2):

J'ai aussi rencontré plusieurs fois le terme **rapporteur**. Plus précisément le titre complet est :

> Rapporteur auprès de revues scientifiques à comité de lecture.

Voici quelques exemples d'emploi :

http://www.lameta.univ-montp1.fr/spip.php?article501&lang=fr

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_des_revues_scientifiques

https://lesignal.info/dictionnaire/revue-scientifique-a-comite-de-lecture

et ainsi de suite.

Voici un [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=relecteur%2Cr%C3%A9viseur%2C%C3%A9valuateur%2Creviewer%2Crapporteur&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crelecteur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9viseur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9valuateur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creviewer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crapporteur%3B%2Cc0) pertinent.